# Applications stop responding when waking up from sleep

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

Lately when I walk away from the computer and it goes into sleep mode, I come back and try to us the computer, all the applications are stuck "not responding".

I can use the computer and browse around, but any application that was open before going to sleep is now stuck. If I try to open Chrome after, it takes forever and 300% CPU. I have to force quit all the apps. Then I reboot (which also takes a long time).

I have 8GB of RAM on my macbook pro, i7. It only started to happen in the last couple of days. I am running Lion.

UPDATE: I now suspect something about the process called "qtkitserver". It happened today without going to sleep mode. One thing in common also was that uTorrent was running. I read online that QTKitServer is responsible for video thumbnails I think - maybe connected to the fact that I'm downloading videos.

Comment: When did you install Lion? Just before this started happening? Could be a memory leak in one of your apps - is Activity Monitor reporting high CPU or RAM usage for anything?

Comment: It started happening a few days after installing Lion - not immediately. I doubt it's a memory leak in one of the app because ALL the 3rd party apps are stuck, but the OS itself is fully responsive. I will look again in Activity Monitor next time it happens.

Comment: "kernel_task" seems to take around 15% CPU and right now 650MB RAM (the system hasn't crashed yet).

Answer (score 1):

You might try seeing if trashing any files that have windowserver in them from `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/` and seeing if that helps to temporarily remedy the issue.

I would expect this to get cleaned up in an official patch once it's certain these files are causing some of the sleep/wake sluggishness - but I've seen anecdotal evidence that this works for some.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried repairing disk permissions and reinstalling Lion?